# running cronjob to overwrite a file

Tags: overwrite

How to overwrite the file while a cronjob is running?I have a command running there every 5 minutes and I want the result to be stored in a text file and it should be overwritten every 5 minutes with new result.How?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a cronjob to write your file in a new file before the next cronjob.

To send content from a file to another file you can use `cat file.txt > file2.txt`or append with `cat file.txt >> file2.txt`